# JSHint is not working

Tags: node.js, jshint

[image][image]I have installed `jshint` using the following command

```
 npm install -g jshint
```

I have test.js file with the following statement

```
      console.log(a)
```

I tested the file using the following command

```
    jshint test.js
```

#### Problem: jshint is not working

It should throw the following error/warning

1. One warning - Missing semicolon
2. One undefined variable - a

#### Contents of .jshintrc file

```
 {

  "bitwise"       : true,     // Prohibit bitwise operators (&, |, ^, etc.).
  "curly"         : true,     // Require {} for every new block or scope.
  "eqeqeq"        : true,     // Require triple equals i.e. `===`.
  "forin"         : true,     // Tolerate `for in` loops without `hasOwnPrototype`.
  "immed"         : true,     // Require immediate invocations to be wrapped in parens e.g. `( function(){}() );`
  "latedef"       : true,     // Prohibit variable use before definition.
  "newcap"        : true,     // Require capitalization of all constructor functions e.g. `new F()`.
  "noarg"         : true,     // Prohibit use of `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee`.
  "noempty"       : true,     // Prohibit use of empty blocks.
  "nonew"         : true,     // Prohibit use of constructors for side-effects.
  "plusplus"      : true,     // Prohibit use of `++` & `--`.
  "regexp"        : true,     // Prohibit `.` and `[^...]` in regular expressions.
  "undef"         : true,     // Require all non-global variables be declared before they are used.
  "strict"        : true,     // Require `use strict` pragma in every file.
  "trailing"      : true     // Prohibit trailing whitespaces.
 }
```

#### Note: I have tried re-installing jshint with [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345412/jshint-not-working) as well.

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: Is there a .jshintrc file who can override settings and disable this errors ?

Comment: @Sachacr There is no .jshintrc file in the following location /node_modules/jshint/

Comment: Ok i should have been more precise :). My question was if there is a .jshintrc in the same directory of test.js ?

Can you show the output of jshint when you launch the command ?

Comment: Yes it is in same directory

Comment: Try with `--show-non-errors`. And show the contents of your `.jshintrc` file.

Comment: @razvan Added screenshot and content of .jshintrc file

Comment: What else do you have in the folder with `test.js` and `.jshintrc`?

Comment: @razvan Only these two files in that folder

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. Try rebooting the system :)

Comment: @razvan Fixed it. Installing Node and npm through the official repositories has always given me trouble. I suspect that this could be due to tools depending on node, when the actual command on Ubuntu is nodejs, which is why creating a symlink should work

Comment: @karthick.k Great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `Node` an npm through the official repositories has always given me trouble. I suspect that this could be due to tools depending on `node`, when the actual command on Ubuntu is `nodejs`.

#### Follow the steps to make jshint work

1. Remove node and npm
2. Reinstall the node using nvm. Following command will do the stuff.

   ```
   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.15.0/install.sh | bash
   source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
   nvm install 0.12 
   nvm use 0.12
   ```

   **Note:** Now you should be able to run Node with the `node` command, you should be able to install modules globally without `sudo`
3. Now install the `jshint` globally using the following command

   ```
   npm install -g jshint
   ```

Now `jshint` will work like a charm :)